# Are "is there x in movie y" questions considered good questions?

Tags: discussion

These following three questions are about spiders in The Hobbit Trilogy:

- https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/28716/do-the-spiders-return-in-the-hobbit-battle-of-the-five-armies
- [Are there any spiders in The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11239/are-there-any-spiders-in-the-hobbit-an-unexpected-journey)
- [Does "The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug" have spiders in it?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15842/does-the-hobbit-the-desolation-of-smaug-have-spiders-in-it)

To me, these sort of questions boil down to "yes or no" with maybe a little bit of wiggle room and fluff added to both the questions and answers to make them long enough to meet quality standards but not really adding quality to them.

Comment: Oh, look who's back from the dead!

Comment: @NapoleonWilson he is back from few days....reopening question and other stuff.

Comment: :-D sometimes i come around and stir up some trouble.